# having problem in touchactions in appium using python

Tags: python, automation, appium

I am making a mobile automation using Python in appium but it keeps on giving me an error in scrolling down the page. Everything is working fine except the scrolling of the page.

This is the code:

```
actions = TouchAction(driver)
actions.scroll_from_element(element, 10, 100)
actions.scroll(10, 100)
actions.perform()
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'TouchAction' object has no attribute 'scroll_from_element'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertical scrolling in Android app using Appium-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179234/vertical-scrolling-in-android-app-using-appium-python)

Comment: try to import from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions instead of from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction.

Answer (score 0):

Change `TouchAction` to `TouchActions`

```py
from selenium import webdriver

action = webdriver.TouchActions(driver)
action.scroll_from_element(year, 0, 0).release(0, 10).perform()
```